# R cannot be resolved for inflating raw queries

Tags: android

I know this is a pretty common question and I looked around the web and this forum for an answer but none of them seem to be working for me. I did the typical stuff like deleted my R.java and cleaned my project, made sure my class did not have a import for the R.java class. I tried rebuilding my project etc.

So here is what I have going on. I am trying to inflate a database from some raw SQL statements. I am using the book The Busy Coders Guide to Advanced Android Development book as a guide to do this.

it gives the following line of code:

```
InputStream stream=ctxt.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.packaged_db);
```

and says the file is located within the res/raw directory like so "res/raw/packaged_db.txt"

I have placed my sql dump file: res/raw/raw_game_data.sql

and here is my line of code that is throwing the error:

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.raw_game_data);
```

any ideas or suggestions on what I am missing?

Thanks,

Comment: We are missing here the log of errors, namely *the* error message, stack. As for your code, localize the part that throws exception and put it here, too.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, only one R.java is built for your entire project, and it is built in only one place, with one package - the package of your app, declared in your manifest. If that package is `com.example.trek`, and you refer to R in a class in `com.example.trek.tribbles` - or any other package - you will need to explicitly import `com.example.trek.R`

You list off some corrective measures without indicating that you understood the actual problem they were intended to correct, or if you had that problem. I'm not unsympathetic to this attitude in the context of *Eclipse*, but you can waste a lot of time this way.  If you understand Java, then you only need to learn aapt to be able to drop down to the command line and attempt the process yourself.

That said, developers.android.com seem to have removed the documentation for aapt.  ...well, don't worry, I'm sure you'll never have problems with Eclipse!

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes I did list off some corrective measures, as I was just stating what it is I have tried based on trying to solve my problem. I am new to Android and Java, only been in it for a week or two, but I am learning.  I did import the R class for my package as you stated and that did seem to fix my problem, thank you.